# Free version of Relevanssi doesn't show ACF fields

Tags: database, advanced-custom-fields

I understand the Premium version of Relevanssi has support for ACF fields built in but I have the free version. I'm working on a way to grab the information from the database and then spit it out on the search results page. This is what I have come up with so far:

/************** FUNCTIONS.PHP ****************/

```
// Relevanssi does not show ACF fields - this is a work-around for specific fields in the DB
function excerpt_function($content, $post, $query) {
    global $wpdb; 

    // Grab everything in the ACF content fields from the DB and spit it out in the search result excerpt. If new ACF modules/fields are added in the future then they need to have their 'modules_#_name_name_content' and so on added to show up in the Relevanssi search.
    $fields = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%modules_%'");
    foreach($fields as $key => $field){ 
        $field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, TRUE); 
        $content .= ' ' . ( is_array($field_value) ? implode(' ', $field_value) : $field_value ); 
    }
    return $content; 
}
add_filter('relevanssi_excerpt_content', 'excerpt_function', 10, 3);
```

I think I need help with:

```
$fields = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%modules_%'");
```

The name of the ACF content in the database always starts with "modules_". If I can figure out how to get the meta value from the meta key with prefix "modules_" then I think I can spit out the results on the search page.

Here is the important part of my search results:

/************** SEARCH.PHP ****************/

```
<h2><?php 
    global $wp_query;
    $some_results = $wp_query->found_posts;
    printf( __( 'There are ' . $some_results . ' Search Results for: %s', 'eqh' ), '<strong>' . get_search_query() . '</strong>' ); ?>
</h2>
<hr />
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="large-3 medium-6 small-12 columns m-bottom">
            <article class="striped clearfix" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
                <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php relevanssi_the_title(); // the_title(); ?></a></h3>

                <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ){ ?>
                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837968/how-to-get-featured-image-of-a-product-in-woocommerce ?>
                <div class="m-bottom f-left m-right"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>"></a></div>

                <?php } else { ?>

                    <div class="m-bottom f-left m-right"><img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/images/placeholder.png" width="" height="" alt="placeholder png" /></div>

                <?php } ?>

                <br clear="all" />
                <?php echo the_excerpt(); // get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                <p><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Read More', 'eqh'); ?></a></p>
            </article>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Comment: The database query is now: $fields = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%modules_%'"); but it spits out ARRAY ARRAY ARRAY ARRAY ARRAY ... on the page. Thoughts?

Comment: This is what the database SQL looks like: SELECT *  FROM `XXXXXXXXXXXX`.`XXX_postmeta` WHERE (CONVERT(`meta_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%modules_%' OR CONVERT(`post_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%modules_%' OR CONVERT(`meta_key` USING utf8) LIKE '%modules_%' OR CONVERT(`meta_value` USING utf8) LIKE '%modules_%'). I'm trying to put together something from this.

Comment: I'm here now with my $wpdb query $fields = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT(meta_key) FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%_content' AND NOT '_modules%'"); but I can't figure out the second part  AND NOT '_modules%' doesn't prevent meta_values from meta_keys beginning with _modules% from showing.

Comment: Just solved it:  AND meta_key NOT LIKE '_modules%'"); is the correct syntax to prevent meta_value from meta_key I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post only the FUNCTIONS.PHP code:

```
// Relevanssi does not show ACF fields by default - this is a work-around for specific fields in the DB
function excerpt_function($content, $post, $query) {
    global $wpdb; 

    // Grab everything in the ACF content fields from the DB and spit it out in the search result excerpt. If new ACF modules/fields are added in the future then they need to have their 'modules_#_name_name_content' and so on added to show up in the Relevanssi search.
    $fields = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT(meta_key) FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%_content' AND meta_key NOT LIKE '_modules%'");
    foreach($fields as $key => $field){ 
        $field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, TRUE); 
        $content .= ' ' . ( is_array($field_value) ? implode(' ', $field_value) : $field_value ); 
    }
    return $content; 
}
add_filter('relevanssi_excerpt_content', 'excerpt_function', 10, 3);
```